# Saving history from a SQL database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview, version-control

I don't think I need to post any code but if I need to I will.

I have created a Windows Form in Visual Studio that creates a record and saves it into a database. I have also added an update function so that I can change the record and save the new changes.

What I need to know though is how to create some kind of version history. i.e. When I click update, I want it to save the previous version so that I can look back at it. Like a bug tracker has a kind of version control but a lot simpler (hopefully).

Would I need a separate database? Could I have another datagridview that when a record is clicked on (or a button) it will show the history of changes for that record?

I've done many searches online and just can't find how to do it or where to look exactly to find this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What actual **database** are you talking about? SQL is just the query language - that doesn't tell us whether you're using `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server` or `db2` or something else entirely - please add a relevant tag

Comment: Sorry about that.  Tag amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are talking about audit trail , take look at this :[Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1019511/Audit-trail-and-data-versioning-with-Csharp-and-MV)

I know this example for MVC but it's the same idea
you only need one table to track changes of the whole database by using json objects that represent "before" and "after"

Comment: Thank you.  That looks exactly like what I need

Comment: Will do but it's going to take some time for me to get it going

Comment: Thanks Cyber Progs, the solution is working perfectly for me, Phill, even if it will take some time for you, you must appreciate the time that other people wasted to search for a solution for you